# Using javascript to call an expressjs restful webservice => result always empty respons

Tags: javascript, web-services, node.js, restful-architecture

Purpose: 
1) Create an website witch runs on a NodeJs webserver.
(expressjs, stylus, jade) + NodeJS 
         2) Create an restful webservice on an NodeJs webserver
            (expressjs) + NodeJS
         3) The website calls an restful web service entry
            (javascript file)

---

With the ubuntu terminal i start the nodeJs for the website an another one for the rest 
webservice.Testing the restful webservice (in browser):

Url:localhost:1337/wines/

Data result is: 
[
  {
    "name": "New wine",
    "Year": "2012",
    "_id": "50e8255197f0b5260f000001"
  }
]

Testing the website
Url: localhost:3000/

This is my javascript file used in the website, here i want to call the 
rest url localhost:1337/wines/ en get the result data.

```
alert('hello!');  (popup)

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:1337/wines/');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
    console.log('response: ' + this.responseText);
    alert("Yes");
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

In the terminals i see that the GET is performed:
Restful terminal: 
GET /wines/ 200 3ms - 93

Website terminal: 
GET / 200 11ms
GET /JavaScript/script.js 304 1ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1ms

When i debug i goes like this: 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   OK
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:1337/wines/');  OK
xhr.send(); OK

xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()   Jump into call back OK
but 'readystate=4 but this.status = 0' and i do not gave an result

In the end i get this error:
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)

---

Result info from firebug (used to debug this java script)

Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Sun, 06 Jan 2013 04:15:07 GMT
X-Powered-By    Express
Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:1337
Origin  //localhost:3000
Referer //localhost:3000/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/13.0.1

---

I searched stack overflow and it could be an 'cross domain issue', therefore i should 
add some javascript to my restful webservice:

```
var express = require('express'),
wine = require('./routes/wines');
var app = express();
app.configure(function () {
app.use(express.logger('dev')); /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
app.use(express.bodyParser());

//Added part
app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "XPOST, GET, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000");
  next();
 });
//Added part

});

app.get('/wines', wine.findAll);
app.get('/wines/:id', wine.findById);
app.post('/wines', wine.addWine);
app.put('/wines/:id', wine.updateWine);
app.delete('/wines/:id', wine.deleteWine);
app.listen(1337);
console.log('Listening on port 1337...');
```

---

> Still no result, anyone an idea how to fix this issue? Many thanx

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the event handler before calling `open()`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
    console.log('response: ' + this.responseText);
    alert("Yes");

  }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:1337/wines/');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thx for the response, i tried this but get the same error, debug info: jump into function() status = 0, readystate = 0 | open | send | jump into function() status = 0, readystate = 4 (same error)